# Are the sentences 'I wish my car would start' and 'I wish the lesson would end' correct?

Tags: wish

The following passage is from 7ESL [1](https://7esl.com/use-wish-in-english-i-wish-if-only/):

> **Wish + Would**
>
> To express that we want something to happen.
>
> Examples:
>
> **I wish my car would start.** (I can’t make it start and I want it to start).  
> **I wish the lesson would end.** (I want it to end).
>
> To express that we want someone to start doing something they do not do.
>
> Example:
>
> **I wish you’d listen to me!**
>
> To express that we want someone to stop doing something which annoys us.
>
> Examples:
>
> **I wish you wouldn’t borrow my clothes!** 
> **I wish my mum wouldn’t phone me every five minutes!**

The following passage is from eslbase [2](https://www.eslbase.com/grammar/wish):

> **Wish + would**
>
> **wish + would + bare infinitive** is used to express impatience, annoyance or dissatisfaction with a present situation or action.
>
> **I wish you would stop smoking.** 
> You are smoking at the moment and it is annoying me.
>
> **I wish it would stop raining.**  
> I’m impatient because it is raining and I want to go outside.
>
> **I wish she’d be quiet.**  
> I am annoyed because she is speaking.
>
> **Wish and hope**
>
> To express that you want something to happen in the future (not wanting a situation to be different, and not implying impatience or annoyance) hope is used instead of wish.
>
> **I hope it’s sunny tomorrow.**  
> **'I wish it was sunny tomorrow'** is not correct.
>
> **I hope she passes her exam next week.**  
> **'I wish she were passing her exam next week'** is not correct.
>
> **I hope the plane doesn’t crash tomorrow.**  
> **'I wish the plane wouldn’t crash tomorrow'** is not correct.

On eslbase Mr Keith Taylor said that when we want something to happen in the future we use the word **hope** instead of the word **wish**. I am confused. On 7ESL I found that when we want something to happen in the future we use **wish+would**.

Are the sentences **'I wish my car would start'**  and **'I wish the lesson would end'** correct? According to Mr Keith Taylor those sentences are wrong. Those sentences should be **'I hope my car starts'** and **'I hope the lesson ends'**. I sent an email to Mr Keith Taylor. I asked him if those sentences are correct and he never answers to me. Maybe Mr Taylor is dead. Can somebody who has English language as their mother language tell me if those sentences are correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those two sentences are correct.

Your quote from eslbase says this as well:

> **Wish + would**
>
> **wish + would + bare infinitive** is used to express impatience, annoyance or dissatisfaction with a present situation or action.

Both "I wish my car would start" and "I wish the lesson would end" are expressing impatience, annoyance or dissatisfaction with a present situation.

When you say "I wish my car would start", you would be in a situation where you are in the car, trying to make it start (or have tried to start it in the past). It is not an abstract wish that the car will start in the future, you would say it because you want the car to start *right now*. (or to have started last time you tried it)

Likewise, "I wish the lesson would end" is not a hope that the lesson will end in the future, but rather you saying that you'd rather not be in the class, and are impatient for it to end. You might continue the sentence with something like:

> I wish the lesson would end, because I'd rather be playing on my Switch.

Comment: It makes no sense to say "I hope the lesson ends", because obviously it will not last forever!

Comment: @Ben Murphy So the sentences 'I hope my car starts' and 'I hope the lesson ends' are wrong. Am I correct?

Comment: @MariosAthanasiou “I hope my car starts” could make sense if you are just worried about it not starting but you haven’t tried it yet(like if you have an old car and it’s very cold, for example). As Kate said above, “I hope the lesson ends” doesn’t make much sense, because every lesson ends. It would be a very strange thing to say.

Comment: @MariosAthanasiou Yes, English is my native language. I’m originally from Australia but I have spent a fair amount of time in the USA. I don’t expect that this question would be different in different regions, though.

Comment: @Ben Murphy Hi! I asked a question. The title is "'I wish my mum wouldn’t phone me every five minutes!' Do I say that sentence to someone while I am talking with my mum on the phone?" [1] Nobody answered my question. I edited it again. I will be happy if you answer it when you have time. I want to know your opinion. Thank you very much!                                              [1]:https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/340464/i-wish-my-mum-wouldn-t-phone-me-every-five-minutes-do-i-say-that-sentence-to